# Is there any method to add a property to a HTable without disabling it first?

Tags: java, hbase

I'm developing HBase Coprocessor. Every time we want to add a new coprocessor to a HTable, we have to first disable it.

Is there anyway to load it dynamically without disabling it?

We came up with an idea of loading coprocessors using classloader and make the loader load coprocessors dynamically, but I'm not sure this will work.
Is there any other idea for this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this Jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7639 
You can do an online update to a table if you are running HBase0.98+